# PHP no value in count

Tags: php, html, oracle

I make a login screen with PHP, but the variable "count" is null, while the username and password are correct in the oracle database.
Please help.

My php code: (Control.php)

```
<?php $conn = oci_connect('TEST', 'TEST', 'CODE');
 $username1 = $_GET['log']; // textbox name
 $password1 = $_GET['pas']; // textbox name
 $array = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT MDW_ACHTERNAAM, MDW_VOORNAAM FROM     
 MDW_VW WHERE MDW_ACHTERNAAM =  '" . $username1 . "'  AND MDW_VOORNAAM = '" .$password1 ."'");
 $query = oci_execute($array);

 $count = oci_num_rows($query);

if($count > 0){ // Here is count 0, while the username and password are correct.
header("Opdracht.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong username.";
}
?>
```

My HTML code form page:

```
<form method="get" action="Control.php">
    Gebruikersnaam: <br /> <input id="Text1" type="text" name="log" maxlength="8" required /> <br />
    Wachtwoord: <br /> <input id="Password1" type="password" name="pas" required /> <br /> <br />

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Inloggen" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to SO! Please try to echo out your $count var and show us the contents.

Comment: @Chilion: There will be 0, what else you expect there?

Comment: @panther, could be a string.

Comment: @Chilion: string from `oci_num_rows`? Maybe string `"1"`, `but "1" > 0` in PHP.

Comment: I echo out my $count var and it is 0

Comment: first of all correct this line as (single quote has been removed) :  

    $array = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT MDW_ACHTERNAAM, MDW_VOORNAAM FROM     
     MDW_VW WHERE MDW_ACHTERNAAM =  " . $username1 . "  AND MDW_VOORNAAM = " .$password1 ."");

Comment: done, but the same error appears ans when I set a break point the $query is false instead of true.

Comment: Are you sure your query is correct? You are sending `password` to be checked in the where against `MDW_VOORNAAM`. Can you show us some of the data in the table?

Comment: When I execute the query in oracle sql development is the answer the same when i type it in the login screen, so I don't think my query is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on `oci_num_rows`says that you need to fetch the result first and not just execute the statement:

*This function does not return number of rows selected! For SELECT statements this function will return the number of rows, that were fetched to the buffer with oci_fetch*() functions.*

( http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php )

In general this function is used to get the number of rows affected by an `update` or `delete`.

In your example, as you have to fetch the result anyway you could as well think of evaluating `count(*)` or something else...